# HTAccess Rewrite multiple domains same rule

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite

From
http://www.example.com/pages/home/view.php?userid=8355

To
http://www.example.com/home/8355

there are many domains I want this rule to apply for on same host and each domain may be with or without www so really:

From /pages/home/view.php?userid=8355

To
/home/8355

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^home/(\d+)/?$ pages/home/view.php?userid=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```